# Django Bower Install Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, bower

I have looked through the threads on this topic and have not been able to figure out a solution.  I am attempting to use the HandsOnTable library (https://handsontable.com/) in a Django app.  I am trying to install the library with django-bower but I cannot seem to configure it properly.  Every time I think I have django-bower installed, the settings.py file does not find django-bower under Installed Apps.  Can somebody direct me to a proper tutorial on how to install/configure django-bower in a Django virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your virtualnev

   ```
   virtualenv test_env
   ```
2. Activate your virtual environment

   ```
   source test_env/bin/activate
   ```
3. Install bower from npm:

   ```
   npm install -g bower
   ```
4. And django-bower package:

   ```
   pip install django-bower
   ```
5. Add django-bower to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings:

   ```
   'djangobower',
   ```
6. Add staticfinder to STATICFILES_FINDERS:

   ```
   'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
   ```
7. Specify path to components root (you need to use absolute path):

   ```
   BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = '/PROJECT_ROOT/components/'
   ```

Ref: http://django-bower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html